# 960 wide triple column layout with padding

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with the way I design triple-column layouts on a 960 wide canvas.

This is a diagram of what I'm attempting:

[image]

I have a DIV element which is 960 wide. It has a 20px padding around the outsides and I need 3 equal columns inside of it.

Can somebody help me with the three columns, so each box and the margins in between are equal? 2 and 4 columns is simple but dividing by 3 doesn't add up equally with the 20px padding in the containing element. When using 2 and 4 columns I use FLOAT:LEFT and an extra element with CLEAR.

```
<style>
.960_element { width:960px; padding:20px; }
.960_element .left {  }
.960_element .middle {  }
.960_element .right {  }
</style>

<div class="960_element">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply set the width of internal elements at 33%? I think it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all your `.960_element` class name is wrong, you cannot define a class name starting with a number

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kG7VH/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="element">     
    <div class="left">h</div>     
    <div class="middle">h</div>     
    <div class="right">h</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.element { width:960px; padding:20px;background-color: #dddddd;margin: 40px;/*margin not required*/}
.element div {background-color: #ff0000;}
.left { height: 200px; width: 32%; display: inline-block;}
.middle { height: 200px; width: 32%; margin-left: 14px;  display: inline-block; }
.right { height: 200px; width: 32%; margin-left: 14px;  display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The element name was just a made up name to describe the element. I was aware of the ruling.

Answer (score 0):

It is more common to put a 10 pixel margin around each item, so that the space between the items adds up to 20 pixels, and the space at the sides is only 10 pixels.

For your situation, your boxes need to be 293 (and a third) pixels wide which is calculated from 960-80/3 (width, minus margins, divided by boxes).

You could end up with a nice even number (300) for boxes if you had a width of 980, or if you were to have 10 pixel margins to the left and right.